# How to deploying flutter app on STMP server with correct domain name?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-bloc

I am deploying Flutter web app on STMP server. My project name is "biti_web". Website domain name is different. Now, I cannot deploy website on main domain name. I can only deploy website to sub domain. i.e. domain_name/biti_web. Putting the web build files in 'biti_web' folder can deploy the web on subdomain. How can I deploy my website on main domain? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing base reference value in index.html file solve the issue.

Replacing `<base href="/biti_web/"> to <base href="/">`